# Reverse engineering - choosing an architecture

Tags: architecture, reverse-engineering

I am reading the book *Reversing: Secrets of reverse engineering* and in the second chapter, the author says:

> if you’re planning on learning reversing and
>   assembly language and have no specific platform in mind, go with IA-32.

This book was written in 2005, so I'm wondering if this is still relevant? If I have no experiences with reverse engineering, assemblers etc. should I chose IA-32?

Answer (score 0):

IA-32 is still the most commonly used architecture for windows as far as applications go, however some applications use AMD64. I suppose it all depends on what it is you are trying to reverse engineer.

Comment: Well I have no particular target, i just want to chose the most expanded architecture. So IA-32 is still actual right?

Comment: That's correct. 64 bit architecture is still fairly new, so there will be a lot more information about IA-32.  By the way, which operating system do you intend on reverse engineering with? If you are using windows, I recommend the disassember called ollydbg. http://www.ollydbg.de/

Answer (score 0):

Most good reverse engineers who I know started with windows IA-32 assembly because windows executables (especially malware) are mostly closed source. You'll find a lot of binary files in windows with IA-32 architectures to practice on. You can switch to another architecture like AT&T after that. It just takes a little bit of adjusting to other architectures when you're already good with IA-32.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, for real world reverse engineering, people are still gonna be starting with x86/IA-32 assembly for years to come. Obviously we've seen an x64/AMD64 takeover recently but those CPUs are capable of running x86 code completely natively (system calls and OS APIs do require the assistance of an emulator like WoW64 though). Crucially, the x86 subset of the x64 instruction set includes the fundamental instructions beginners are going to want to learn about first anyway.

Of course, in reverse engineering there's a different and much more compelling incentive to care about IA-32 code specifically which is the massive availability of native x86 programs. From a pure reversing standpoint, you really only need to know *anything* about x64 CPUs if you plan to go to work on programs for them.

As I already hinted at, the differences are nowhere near substantial enough to render x86 knowledge worthless. There's some changes on the architecture side (e.g. extended registers like `RAX` and changes to the things you can use them for) and some on the instruction set side (e.g. some of your common instructions will be expecting 64-bit register operands) but there's far more that's the same than different.

There are other platforms, such as ARM, that your question would've also been talking about but these aren't prevalent in the kind of devices you're interested in. The suggestion to learn x86 assembly by default is a good one.